# Why when I use some queries in unit tests the created item doesn't load?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xunit, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using **XUnit** on the **boilerplate** (abp 6.0.0) and in the unit test example below I'm creating a "SwitchDto" and in the variable "isHere" I checked it and it was created.

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test_Example()
{
    var switchDto = await _switchAppService.CreateAsync(SwitchTr1_Valid_Dto);
    var id = switchDto.Id;
    
    await UsingDbContextAsync(async context =>
    {
        var isHere = await context.Switch.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
    });

    using var switchController = new SwitchController(_switchAppService);
    using var switchInterfaceController = new SwitchInterfaceController(_switchInterfaceAppService);

    switchDto = await _switchAppService.UpdateAsync(switchDto);
    switchDto.Hostname.ShouldBe("switchHost");

    await UsingDbContextAsync(async context =>
    {
        var _switch = await context.Switch.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
        _switch.ShouldNotBeNull();
        _switch.SerialNumber.ShouldBe("5678");
    });
}
```

But on "UpdateAsync" I get an error during a validation as it can't find the "switch" created in the method below:

```
public override async Task<SwitchDto> GetAsync(EntityDto<int> input)
{
    CheckGetPermission();

    Switch sw = await Repository.GetAllIncluding(i => i.TechnicalRoom)
        .Include(i => i.SwitchManufacturerModel)
        .ThenInclude(i => i.SwitchBrand)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == input.Id);

    return MapToEntityDto(sw);
}
```

**I already tried** to execute the `UpdateAsync` method in the block `UsingDbContextAsync`.

The problem only happens during unit tests, if I run the application the same method brings the values normally.

Why when I use this queries above the created item doesn't load?

Comment: are you using database in your unit tests? what db?

Comment: @LeiYang I use EF and Postgre, but I mocked my service with Resolve from AbpIntegratedTestBase.

Comment: Does `isHere.ShouldNotBeNull()` pass?

Comment: @aaron, yes, it does. I already understand the problem. In "UpdateAsync" I use another method that join some tables to validate some rules and i didnt mock these items. I'll answer with the complete solution soon.